# css rounded border sizing with white space and anti-aliasing

Tags: css, border-layout

I've tried putting together a simple scenario with css for a card style layout.

It looks ok on a 22 inch monitor, but when viewed on my samsung tv 1920x1080 resolution it does not look good.

It looks like the border has a white gap in it caused by anti-aliasing.

[image: zoomed border]

**html**

```
<main>
  <div class="card-holder">
    <div class="card-header">
      <div class="card-icon">
        <span class="icon icon-bell"></span>
      </div>
      <span class="card-title">Title</span>
    </div>

    <div class="card-about">
      <span>Some about text.</span>
    </div>

  </div>
</main>
```

**css**

```
.card-holder {
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
  border: 3px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-spacing: 0;

  overflow: hidden;
  width: 300px;
}

.card-header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;

  padding: 5px;

  background-color: rgb(0, 64, 255);
  color: #fff;

  overflow: hidden;
}

.card-title {
  display: inline-block;
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

.card-about {
  display: block;
}

.card-icon {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;

  height: 64px;
  width: 64px;
}

.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 48px;
  width: 48px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.icon-bell {
  background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/icon-bell-black.svg);
}
```

When I zoom the browser to 80% then a white line appears at the right hand side of the card.

[image: white line]

Is there a recommended approach to make this scenario work nicely across different zoom levels and monitor resolutions?

I've been tearing my hair out.

**Update**

I made a [codepen here](https://codepen.io/andrewthedev/pen/OJMvLJE)

Comment: You can also swap your bg colors https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/ZEQrgJw don't cure, avoid it ;)

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing relative and fixed units. Things like `em` and `%` will be different based on the browser, device, and zoom. Try using all relative or all fixed so the browser isn't trying to interpret them differently.

Example:

```
border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
```

vs

```
border-radius: 1em 1em 0px 0px;
```

Comment: I was using pixels first, thus `border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;` still has the same white gap effect.

Comment: The more of those differences you can eliminate the better. You might also want to try with nice round numbers for width, height, etc to prove it's really an aliasing issue. Zoom does strange stuff in all browsers so you may not be able to eliminate that. But a different screen resolution shouldn't be a problem (though browsers in TVs aren't exactly standards based)